# How to setup a systemd service with root access?

Tags: python, sudo, systemd, services

## Description

I am trying to make a systemd service file to run a python script to print something using thermal printer. **escpos** is the library I am using to access the control of thermal printer. However escpos require sudo to access the usb device.

## Question

How to make a systemd service file such that the exec command get the root access? Base on some answer on internet, if I don't set anything to User, the default exec should get root access automatically. But I still getting trouble to make my program run. Hope anyone can help me to spot my mistake.

## Code

### python

File: ***/usr/local/etc/test/testPrint.py***

```
from escpos.printer import Usb
#require escpos use "pip install python-escpos" to install the library
""" Seiko Epson Corp. Receipt Printer (EPSON TM-T88III) """
p = Usb(0x4b43, 0x3538, 0, 0x82, 0x02)
p.text("Hello World\n")
p.text("\n\n\n")
p.cut()
```

I can run `sudo python3 /usr/local/etc/test/testPrint.py` and print the text from the thermal printer without any problem.

### Service File

File: ***/etc/systemd/system/testPrint.service***

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Python escpos print
After=network.target
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/etc/test/testPrint.py
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And when I try to run the command `sudo systemctl start testPrint.service`. It gives error

### Error log

Command: `sudo journalctl -u testPrint.service`:

```
python3.5[27149]: Traceback (most recent call last):
python3.5[27149]:   File "/usr/local/etc/test/testPrint.py", 
python3.5[27149]:     from escpos.printer import Usb
python3.5[27149]: ImportError: No module named 'escpos'
systemd[1]: testPrint.service: Main process exited, code=exit
systemd[1]: Failed to start Test python escpos print.
systemd[1]: testPrint.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: testPrint.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

Which is the same error, if I run python without sudo "**python3 printTest.py**"

## Edit:

Just to give out some extra info. I use **sudo pip3 install python-escpos** to install the module.
My OS is **Ubuntu 16.04**

Comment: How did you install `escpos`?  `sudo pip3 install escpos` or `pip3 install escpos`?  Or was this in a virtualenv you used for escpos?  Because you need the module installed systemwide with `sudo pip3 install` for it to be able to use `escpos`.

Comment: I use *sudo pip3 install python-escpos* to install the library

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please don’t put the solution into the question. Use the answer field below instead. https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer Also [don’t add “SOLVED” to the title](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7413/250300). In order to mark your question _solved_ in the right way, you may [_accept_ the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking on the tick mark (✓) next to it) that helped you. In case the [helpful answer was posted by you](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer), you'll have to wait 2 days before being able to accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I am still learning to be a part of AskUbuntu community.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.

This bug is not caused by root permission, but rather the **escpos** module are not install correctly under root user. After I reinstall the **escpos** by `sudo pip3 install python-escpos` all codes work accordingly and is able to print the text.